# Laser engraving with 3018 pro can be controlled with basic Openbuilds controls, but engraving a file causes errors

Tags: g-code, cnc

I've been struggling with this for the past three days, and I can't seem to solve this problem. I'm on a Mac and trying to let my 3018 pro cnc machine laser engrave an image, but whatever I do, it always gives this error: "Error 20 - Unsupported or invalid-code command found in block. [M106 P0 S255]. When I remove this line and try to run it I get this error: "ALARM:  - Reset while in motion. Grbl cannot guarantee position. Lost steps are likely, Re-homing Aladeen highly recommended. [undefined]"

The part of my code that might be relevant is:

;Header Start[image]
;renderMethod: point
;file_total_lines: 1057930
;estimated_time(s): 27125.609
;is_rotate: false
;diameter: 40
;max_x(mm): 153.811
;max_y(mm): 108.78899999999999
;max_z(mm): 0
;max_b(mm): 0
;min_x(mm): 8.631
;min_y(mm): 8.658999999999999
;min_b(mm): 0
;min_z(mm): 0
;work_speed(mm/minute): 800
;jog_speed(mm/minute): 3000
;power(%): 60
;work_size_x: 320
;work_size_y: 350
;origin: bottom-left
;thumbnail: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0
;Header End

; Laser multi-pass, pass 1 with Z = 0
; G-code for laser engraving
; Generated by Snapmaker Luban
; G-code START <<<
G90
G21
M106 P0 S255
G0 F3000
G1 F800
G1 X8.63 Y108.79
M3 P60 S153
M3
G4 P5
M5
G1 X8.63 Y108.45
M3
G4 P5
M5[image]

I have read something that it has something to do with not having installed the CH340 driver, so I tried that, and it didn't work. Generating codes from the same image using different software resulted in the same error,

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of machine you have? M106 P0 S255 is a command to set a motor speed of some sort. On some machines, this is a fan.

Comment: Also, the g-code doesn't include a G28 command to set the tool to the home position, which is probably where the alarm is coming from.